# Repeated pattern image as background in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to set an image as background and repeat it throughout the screen. In UIKit it is as simple as this single line of code:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background.png"))
```

Is there an equivalent in SwiftUI?

```
var body: some View {
  HStack {
    VStack {
      Spacer()
    }
    Spacer()
  }
  .background(
    Image("background") // Need this pattern image repeated throughout the page
  )
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the resizable modifier and set the resizing mode to `Image.ResizingMode.tile`.

```
Image("background")
    .resizable(resizingMode: .tile)
```

Comment: When using svg files, the path within the svg file must be at the root level. I had some svg files with the path contained in a layer or group. Those would not work with the tile effect. Do you know of any way to resize these tiles programmatically? I ultimately just used small png files.